# SSIS Derive timestamp column into date and time columns

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, type-conversion, derived-column

I have this Timestr in varchar `28/12/2016 16:39:01`

How to Derived the column into date and time in SSIS

**Desired result**

Date `2016-12-28` in Date format

Time `16:39:01` in time format

This is what i have in SQL so far

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST((SUBSTRING(TimeStr,12,8)) AS DATETIME),'hh:mm:ss tt') AS Time
```

Code [image]

Result [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SSIS expressions you can try:

**DATE**

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(Timestr,7,4) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(Timestr,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Timestr,1,2))
```

**TIME**

```
(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(Timestr,12,8))
```

Your Derived Column settings should look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Avoid miliseconds in `DT_DBTIME`

```
(DT_DBTIME2,0)(SUBSTRING(Timestr,12,8))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Missed the SSIS key item  +1

Comment: This the result i got from above code.. very close to what i m looking for but how to get rid of those extra 000000 for time column  Date - 2016-11-30 Time -  07:29:21.0000000

Comment: @alejandrozuleta still unable to get rid of the millisenconds. result from the code Time - 07:29:21.0000000.

Comment: @Jason312, What is the data type of the column where you are inserting the values? How are you visualizating the data in the source? Also bear in mind formating should be handled in the presentation instead of the backend.

Comment: I have tried datetime and time both still unable rid of the milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

To convert your varchar into a datetime, I would recomment Try_Convert() if 2012+, if not just Convert() would do the trick provided your data is reasonable.

```
try_convert(datetime,Timestr,103)  --  returns 2016-12-28 16:39:01.000
```

To use Format()

```
Declare @Timestr varchar(25) = '28/12/2016 16:39:01'
Select DateTime12 = format(try_convert(datetime,@Timestr,103),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt')
      ,DateOnly   = format(try_convert(datetime,@Timestr,103),'yyyy-MM-dd')
      ,Time12     = format(try_convert(datetime,@Timestr,103),'hh:mm:ss tt')
      ,Time24     = format(try_convert(datetime,@Timestr,103),'HH:mm:ss')
```

Returns

```
DateTime12                DateOnly      Time12         Time24
2016-12-28 04:39:01 PM    2016-12-28    04:39:01 PM    16:39:01
```

Comment: Sorry i m new to this, how to convert the above code in SSIS format on derived column